# Code Error 307 in volley

Tags: java, android, android-volley

i have a problem, i need a request with method post and i use volley and the response it's

```
public void QueryPost() {

 final RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this); //Debemos pasar el contexto de la actividad(Activity)
 StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, "http://pruebas/prueba.php", new Response.Listener < String > () {
  @Override
  public void onResponse(String response) { //Si la respuesta es positiva,si todo salio OK

   Log.e("respuesta ---- --- -- --   ", response);

  }
 }, new Response.ErrorListener() { //En el caso de que ocurra un error X
  @Override
  public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
   Log.e("Error: ", error.getMessage() + ""); //Se mostrara el error producido
  }
 });

 queue.add(stringRequest);

}
```

**Code Error 307**

```
BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 307 for
```

Comment: wow your issue is resolved good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Volley 307 error Code

**HTTP Error 307 - Temporary redirect**

`307` is the status code that is sent when a document is temporarily available at a different URL, which is also returned. There is very little difference between a `302 status code` and a `307 status code`. 307 was created as another, less ambiguous, version of the 302 status code.

Comment: thanks for you answerd,I solved my problem,the URL need / after  prueba.php/